# iPhone iOS: Local Notifications Aren't Appearing

Tags: xcode, datepicker, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I'm writing an app that sends the user an alert through the Notification Center when an event date is approaching. But when I set the date in the date picker and close the app, the notification doesn't appear. I already enabled Push Notifications in my provisioning profiles. It may be because of my objectForKey area. I have 2 nibs (one for iPhone, one for iPad) named ImportantDatesViewController_iPhone1 and ImportantDatesViewController_iPad1. Should I change the objectForKey area to the nib name instead of just "ImportantDatesViewController"? And my .h and .m file names are simply ImportantDatesViewController also. Sorry, I'm still very new at this and learning as I go.
Here is all the code in my project that deals with the notification center, this is what I put in my view controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm'/'dd'/'yyyy"];

NSDate *eventDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ImportantDatesViewController.selectedDate"];


localNotif.fireDate = [eventDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*60*60];
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

localNotif.alertBody = @"Event coming in three days!";

localNotif.alertAction = nil;

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];    

return YES;
```

}

I also added this code in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in the App Delegate at the bottom, and I thought it would do the trick:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just a side note, I previously posted about this but posted it incorrectly, I deleted the previous one and posted this in the correct format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Local Notifications Won't Appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958898/iphone-local-notifications-wont-appear)

Answer (score 4):

Your telling it to fire a notification immediately when you set it and your setting it for a time before now by setting (NOW)-60*60*60.The notification has passed already.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotif];
```

if you want to set it for a specific time:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past, the notification is delivered immediately.
As a side note make sure to set the timeZone and Locale to the ones you want.

Comment: I never really checked that until you just mentioned it, But mine shows up in there. I don't see any reason it won't if your testing on a device.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, so would -60*60*60 be the correct formula for trying to send a notification 60 hours before the date the user set on the date picker arrives?

Comment: I can't be sure because I work a lot with NSDateComponents and would just set the hours to -60. But your solution looks solid also, I just can't be 100% sure. Sometimes there is more than one way to do the same thing.

Comment: Ah crap, actually it didn't work, sorry I was mistaken. I changed it to `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];` but it didn't seem to make a difference. Will it still work if the device is in sleep mode and the app is not running? I also edited the OP with more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
UILocalNotifications *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

   if (localNotif == nil) return;
  NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date]   dateByAddingTimeInterval:900] ;  //15 min

            localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
            localNotif.alertBody = @"Parking your CAR 15 Minutes reached..";
            //    localNotif.repeatInterval=kCFCalendarUnitMinute;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code for LocalNotification that worked for my project.

This code block in AppDelegate file :

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return YES;
    }

    // This code block is invoked when application is in foreground (active-mode) 
    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

        UIAlertView *notificationAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification"    message:@"This local notification" 
        delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [notificationAlert show];
       // NSLog(@"didReceiveLocalNotification");
    }
```

This code block in .m file of any ViewController :

```
-(IBAction)startLocalNotification {  // Bind this method to UIButton action
    NSLog(@"startLocalNotification");

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:7];
    notification.alertBody = @"This is local notification!";
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 10;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];    
}
```

The above code display an AlertView after time interval of 7 seconds when pressed on button that binds “startLocalNotification”
If application is in background then it displays BadgeNumber as 10 and with default notification sound.